# Protractor using CTRL + END

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing

I'm using protractor for angular end-to-end.
In order to send keys to an element, I use:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('end').perform();
```

The problem is it doesn't work at all.
I don't know what I'am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below one

**Option1:**

```
var elm = element(by.model('locator'));
elm.sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.END));
```

**Option 2:**

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys(protractor.Key.END).perform();
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Mark the answer as correct.If it really helped to resolve the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to CRTL + End, try:

`browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL + protractor.Key.END).perform();`

Comment: Ok. I double checked it. The tricky thing is that you need to combine (using `+`) both keys in single `sendKeys()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `protractor.Key.END`

`browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).keyDown(protractor.Key.END).perform();`

Also, read: [A list of Protractor.js key constants](https://gist.github.com/boxmein/f86b6e196d3c0c472f302c80f7388704)

***EDIT***

also try

`browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.END)).perform()`

**OR**

`browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, protractor.Key.END).perform()`

Comment: what machine/OS are you using? or what keyboard type? there's a possibility of it affecting browser behavior.

Comment: I use Windows 10, I use AZERTY keyboard

Comment: Hey, that's great. just make sure to also edit your question with the exact answer that worked for you as we all have given 2-3 options to try. it will help some one in need in future.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when going to the bottom of a large grid element

(js protractor async)

```
    await <anElementOnYourGrid>.click();
    await browser.sleep(1000);
    await browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.END).perform();
```